# How to log in to SugarCRM using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sugarcrm

I have searched the whole internet and I can't find a working way to log in to SugarCRM with Javascript.  This is as close as I've gotten:

```
var params = { 
   user_auth:{  
     user_name:'jim',   
     password:'jim',   
     encryption:'PLAIN' 
   }, 
   application_name: 'SugarCRM RestAPI Example'
}
var restdata = JSON.stringify(params);

$.ajax({ 
   type: "POST", 
   url: "http://alzjgk0569.trial.sugarcrm.com/service/v4/rest.php?jsoncallback=?", 
   data: {
     method: "login",
     input_type: "JSON",
     response_type: "JSON",
     rest_data: restData
   }, 
   dataType:"jsonp", 
   success: function(result) {alert("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));},
   failure: function() {alert("failed");}
});
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

p.s. I should mention that the following works just fine:

```
<form action="https://alzjgk0569.trial.sugarcrm.com/rest/v10/oauth2/token" method="post">       
  grant_type: <input type="text" name="grant_type" value="password"><br>
  client_id: <input type="text" name="client_id" value="sugar"><br>
  client_secret: <input type="text" name="client_secret" value=""><br>
  username: <input type="text" name="username" value="jim"><br>
  password: <input type="text" name="password" value="jim"><br>
  platform: <input type="text" name="platform" value="base"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Edit:
I got it working by changing the url to begin with "https://" when this page is served with "https".  But the response is this:

```
{\"user_auth\":{\"user_name\":\"jim\",\"password\":\"jim\",\"encryption\":\"PLAIN\"},\"application_name\":\"SugarCRM RestAPI Example\"}" = {"id":"1cg0ji99ouq0st6jndlcbo3075","module_name":"Users","name_value_list":{"user_id":{"name":"user_id","value":"seed_jim_id"},"user_name":{"name":"user_name","value":"jim"},"user_language":{"name":"user_language","value":"en_us"},"user_currency_id":{"name":"user_currency_id","value":"-99"},"user_is_admin":{"name":"user_is_admin","value":false},"user_default_team_id":{"name":"user_default_team_id","value":"1"},"user_default_dateformat":{"name":"user_default_dateformat","value":"m/d/Y"},"user_default_timeformat":{"name":"user_default_timeformat","value":"h:ia"},"user_number_seperator":{"name":"user_number_seperator","value":","},"user_decimal_seperator":{"name":"user_decimal_seperator","value":"."},"mobile_max_list_entries":{"name":"mobile_max_list_entries","value":10},"mobile_max_subpanel_entries":{"name":"mobile_max_subpanel_entries","value":3},"user_currency_name":{"name":"user_currency_name","value":"US Dollar"}}}
```

This is completely useless information.  It has no token, so it's not really even a real login.  I'm giving up on client side SugarCRM login, and going back to server side with PHP, which I know works.

Comment: What happens when you change `$.ajax` `type` to `GET`?

Answer (score 2):

You actually have the answer here.  Your login token is the id value in the response you posted.

Answer (score 0):

SugarCRM API calls are better on the server side:
1. More secure
2. Does not have cross domain request issue due to the Same Origin Policy enforced by browsers. So JSONP is not needed.